# gulp-babel and babel-preset-es2015 doesn't work well in WebStorm 2017

Tags: webstorm, gulp-babel

I want to install `gulp-babel` and `babel-preset-es2015` in my project in WebStorm 2017, but after I install them in `node_modules` it is very slow to reopen the project in WebStorm. I have excluded the `node_modules` like this:

[image]

I can't use babel to transform the ES6 files. WebStorm becomes very slow and it stucks.

Answer (score 0):

Please exclude the build destination folder ('dist' in your project) from the project: right-click on it in the Project view and select Mark as Excluded. It seems that the build process generates the files in the 'dist' folder on changes and the IDE keeps re-analyzing them considering them new files.